# Print the characters by iterating in c

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, char, c-strings

```c
#include <stdio.h>

void fun(char *p) {
    if (p) {
        printf("%c", *p);
        p++;    
    }
}

int main() {
    fun("Y32Y567");
    return 0;
}
```

**Output:Y**

**Expected Output:Y32Y567**

My questions why it is not working the expected way?

Comment: Why would you expect any iteration whatsoever from a code path that has no iteration loop, nor recursion to simulate said-same? *Run your code in a **debugger***. You will see all this does is step into the function, test `p`, then print `Y`, then increment `p` (for no apparent reason), then exit the function, then exit `main`.

Answer (score 6):

The function `fun` only prints one character if it enters the `if`. You probably meant to use a `while` loop, not a single `if` condition. Additionally, your condition is wrong - `p` evaluates to a true-thy as long as it's not `NULL`, which won't happen if you passed a string literal. You probably meant to test `*p`, i.e., the character `p` points to:

```c
void fun(char* p)
{
        while (*p) /* Here */
        {
            printf("%c",*p);
            p++;    
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The function outputs just one character if the passed pointer `p` is not equal to NULL because any loop in the function is absent. The function contains only if statement that checks the pointer p.

```
void fun(char* p)
{
        if(p)
        {
            printf("%c",*p);
            p++;    
        }
}
```

You need a loop that will output characters of the pointed string.

But for starters the function parameter should have the qualifier `const` because the pointed string is not changed within the function.

The function can look the following way

```
void fun( const char* p)
{
        if ( p )
        {
            while ( *p ) putchar( *p++ );
        }
}
```

But the function will be more general if it will have a second parameter that specifiers a file. For example

```
FILE * fun( const char* p, FILE *fp )
{
        if ( p )
        {
            while ( *p ) fputc( *p++, fp );
        }

        return fp;
}
```

In this case you can output a string in a file.

Here is a demonstrative program

```
#include <stdio.h>

FILE * fun( const char* p, FILE *fp )
{
        if ( p )
        {
            while ( *p ) fputc( *p++, fp );
        }

        return fp;
}

int main(void) 
{
    fputc( '\n', fun( "Y32Y567", stdout ) );
    
    return 0;
}
```

Of course you could output a string as whole without a loop with one statement. For example

```
#include <stdio.h>

FILE * fun( const char* p, FILE *fp )
{
        if ( p )
        {
            fputs( p, fp );
        }

        return fp;
}

int main(void) 
{
    fputc( '\n', fun( "Y32Y567", stdout ) );
    
    return 0;
}
```